# Modifying OriginalFilename string according to platform target

Tags: c++, macros, visual-studio-2017, resources

I have a standard C++ console application built with Visual Studio 2017. I added a **VS_VERSION_INFO resource** by right-clicking on project name and then choosing Add, Resource, Version. I would like to set the **OriginalFilename** string to be **MyProject.x86** **when** I build the project **targeting x86** and **MyProject.x64** **when** I build **targeting x64**. I tried editing the automatically produced .rc file with Notepad but I always obtain that string to be "Nothing_is_defined"

```
#ifdef _M_X64 // Building to x64
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "Setup.x64"
#elif _M_IX86 // Building to x86
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "Setup.x86"
#else
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "Nothing_is_defined"
#endif
```

What should I do to change that string according to platform target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are compiled with separate resource compiler tool. This tool has separate set of preprocessor defines that can be adjusted at Project Properties -> Resources -> General tab. By default target-specific macros such as `_M_X64` (that are defined by C++ compiler) are not defined for resource compiler so you'll need to supply them manually.